# Uploading images with unique names (PHP)

Tags: php

I am currently working on a simple upload script.

However, I have a problem with users uploading images from their iPhones since iPhone names all of the images "image.jpg" and you can't have two images with the same name.

Is there any way to add a random string to the file name in the uploading process below? I'm new to PHP!

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  } else {
    if (file_exists("../../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $image_link = 'http://www.martahedin.com/EveryLife/upload/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   echo $image_link;
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to have a different filename try:
rand(0,9999)

like this:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../../upload/" .rand(0,99999). $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

UPDATED:

```
$newName = rand(0,99999). $_FILES["file"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../../upload/" . $newName);

$image_link = 'http://www.martahedin.com/EveryLife/upload/' . $newName;


   echo $image_link;
```

Comment: The file are still being named "image.jpg"... Any ideas?

Comment: I think you may be calling it wrong, can you post your updated code?

Comment: Sorry. The images have unique names but the $image_link; is still image.jpg even though if the file is called something else. Any ideas about that?

Comment: You're welcome :)  
Will the person who downvoted me be so kind as to tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

The server-side file name is specified on this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

If you want to add a unique string to that file name, you can add it to that line.  One option, for example, could just be to prepend a unique string to the existing file name:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../../upload/" . uniqid() . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified to do what you wish.  Change the $destination variable to whatever format you desire.  Change the $uniquevalue to whatever you wish to use for uniqueness.

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

// Get the file extension
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Get the file name without the extension
$filename = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"], ".$extension");

// Define your unique identifier - this example uses unix timestamp
$uniquevalue = time();

// Combine the above parts in the form you wish
$destination = $filename . '-' . $uniquevalue . '.' . $extension;

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  } else {
    if (file_exists("../../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    } else {
      // Changed $_FILES["file"]["name"] to $destination

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../../upload/" . $destination);
      $image_link = 'http://www.martahedin.com/EveryLife/upload/' . $destination;
   echo $image_link;
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this part of code

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

by

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../upload/" . uniqid() . "_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Hope it helps